# wpf custom stackpanel datatrigger

Tags: wpf-controls, datatrigger

I'm trying to create a custom StackPanel that performs an animation (scale) when a property on a viewmodel changes. I've created a Dependency Property in my derived class

```
public partial class TrgScaleStackPanel : StackPanel
{
    #region TriggerValue DP

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Value which is being displayed
    /// </summary>
    public bool TriggerValue
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(TriggerValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TriggerValueProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identified the Label dependency property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TriggerValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TriggerValue", typeof(bool),
          typeof(TrgScaleStackPanel), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    #endregion
    public TrgScaleStackPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In the XAML I have added Style with a DataTrigger that binds to the dependency property

```
<StackPanel x:Class="StackPanelDemo.TrgScaleStackPanel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         x:Name="TrgScaleParent"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<StackPanel.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TrgScaleParent.TriggerValue}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</StackPanel.Style>
```

On my test window I have

```
                <stackPanelDemo:TrgScaleStackPanel TriggerValue="{Binding SettingsViewVisible}">
                <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
                <Button>Goodbye</Button>
                <stackPanelDemo:TrgScaleStackPanel.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="0" />
                </stackPanelDemo:TrgScaleStackPanel.LayoutTransform>
            </stackPanelDemo:TrgScaleStackPanel>
```

It builds and runs but unfortunately, the trigger doesn't fire. I suspect it is something to do with the data context but am not really sure.

Could someone enlighten me as to where I'm going wrong

Comment: I have added a callback to the Dependency Property and the "value" is changing but the trigger is not firing.

Answer (score 0):

After much fiddling I discovered that I needed to use

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TriggerValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
```

Unfortunately, I have got much further in creating a truly configurable StackPanel with scale animation as one runs into a

> cannot freeze this storyboard timeline tree for use across thread

when one tries to bind the "To" property of a DoubleAnimation. This means that I can't configure direction at design time with a dependency property. If anyone knows of a way to get past this please let me know!!!

Another interesting issue was that unless I specified a LayoutTransform when using my custom StackPanel the animation simply doesn't fire. I have no idea why?

If anyone knows of a better way to do this please let me know. It may be my approach is wrong?